# CURL login attempt doesn't populate password field

Tags: php, curl, authentication

Attempting a secure login via curl, code below. The Username field populates fine, which I've taken from the name attribute of the input tag.

I've done the same for the password field but this doesn't show anything in the input.

I saw a post suggest this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` but it's not achieving any success and I've also tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8');` to no avail. Thanks.

```
<?php
// HTTP authentication

$url = "https://login.com/login.php";

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"loginUsername=myUsernameHere&loginPassword=myPasswordHere");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: `I've done the same for the password field but this doesn't show anything in the input.` I'm not sure what you mean by this. After you execute this script, how do you know `The Username field populates fine, which I've taken from the name attribute of the input tag.` as your only output is the result from `curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: The output of curl_exec, from the man page is `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure. ` so this is why I'm confused on how you know `The Username field populates fine`

Comment: Can we see the contents of `login.php`?

Comment: Hey. The echoed result shows the login form with a populated username input field, but empty password input field.

Comment: This is difficult to diagnose as the cURL looks correct. We must see the contents of `login.php` to provide a solution. I have a feeling that `login.php` isn't looking for `$_POST['loginPassword']` but something else

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/JNZjgT9) is how it looks when I run the script. And here are the inputs I'm attempting to fill 

`<DIV>
<INPUT NAME="loginUsername" VALUE="DCL1" ID="loginUsernameNew" DEFAULTTEXT="Username" TYPE="text" TABINDEX="1" />
</DIV> 
<DIV>
<INPUT TYPE="password" TABINDEX="2" NAME="loginPassword" ID="loginPasswordNew" VALUE="" DEFAULTTEXT="Password" ></INPUT>
</DIV>`

Comment: I'm sorry Jamie I don't think I can be of much help. Can you confirm that the credentials are correct? Is that HTML code from the site you are trying to login to? More importantly; Why don't you have access to the php code on `login.php` that you are trying to create a "secure login" with? Please understand my skepticism and don't take offense if I ask; Are you attempting to break into someones website?

Comment: Haha no... I'm trying to login to our ESP so I can automate pulling reports for insertion into our dashboard. Their API doesn't support this so this is a path I thought might work well. I appreciate your concern though :)

Comment: In that case I'm baffled. May I suggest using the credentials in your script and passing them via your browser using dev tools to see what's going on? Forging your own header packet may be a good way to see if you're missing any hidden securities.

Comment: I feel like the script is executing fine and password is getting sent + processed but login.php is returning an incorrect login/blocked by another security feature. See https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/ for more details. Also double check you're not upagainst [HMAC post protection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

Comment: Another solution may be to use Javascript to pull the reports from your browser as you access the page and then send to your server for further processing via AJAX

Comment: Thanks for your help @IsThisJavascript, I'll do some reading up on those suggestions - very much appreciated!